# Disabling skype messaging sound on Nexus 7

Tags: skype, nexus-7

It seems you can turn off all notifications and alerts, but I like getting text notifications.

The spammy sound that comes by default is most certainly annoying, and there doesn't seem to be any option to disable that without losing text notifications too.

Does anyone know how to disable just the Skype sound, whilst keeping the text notification?

Answer (score 2):

#### Skype Settings -> Notifications

[image: screenshot]